# AWS Athena - Partition missing

Tags: amazon-athena

Have a process where I am trying to consolidate multiple small JSON files into a large JSON file.

I have been able to achieve this with:

```
    query = "CREATE TABLE {0} WITH ( external_location='{1}', write_compression = 'NONE', format = 'JSON') AS SELECT * FROM standardtable WHERE partition_0 = '{0}'".format(dataset_name,outputjson)

    client = boto3.client('athena')
    
    # Create a Athena table with the dataset name, and create a Json from the newly created Athena table.
    # Athena is crawling the hylandlm_dataset S3 bucket and creating a row for each json file within the bucket.
    # PartionID is the subfolder name(dataset name). Creating a table based on that partionID. Creating a JSON from the table

    try:
        response = client.start_query_execution(
            QueryString=query,
            QueryExecutionContext={
                'Database': DATABASE
            },
            ResultConfiguration={
                'OutputLocation': output,
            }
        )
```

I've had issues updating Athena's results when the system creates a new folder in S3, which is what partition_0 is. Each subfolder within S3 bucket becomes a partition and unfortunately we will frequently create a sub-folder with multiple jsons that need to be consolidated.

Based on some answers from stackoverflow, it seems like there are a few options

1. Use MSCK REPAIR TABLE standardtable
2. ALTER TABLE standardtable ADD PARTITION (partition_0={newdatasetname}) location = s3://...
3. Re-run the Glue Crawler

For some reason, option 1 doesn't update the table for me and provides a "Partitions not in metastore:" message.

Option 2 seems to work and will work nicely since I can run that command on creation of the new subfolder.

Option 3 also works but I'm worried about cost of crawling

Which really brings me to my question. What is the cost with running the ALTER TABLE command vs re-run the Glue Crawler? Is there any benefit to re-running the Glue Crawler vs the ALTER TABLE?

Tried all three options